# Issues getting UuidToStringW to generate a proper UUID string

Tags: printing, uuid, widechar

Looking at replacing some id's in our main code base with UUIDs so that the ids can be used with multiple instances of our software.  Before adding this functionality, I thought I would check out how to use these calls in a console app.

I can get the ASCII version working but I cannot get the wide character string version to work.  The wide character version will only generate appears to be the first part of the string as a short while the ASCII version generates the whole UUID.  Below is the code for the test, compiled run on VS2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rpc.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Rpcrt4.lib")

int main()
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Generate the UUID
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UUID newUUID;
    RPC_STATUS resultTypeCreate = UuidCreate(&newUUID);
    switch (resultTypeCreate)
    {
        case RPC_S_OK:
            std::cout << "UUID generated properly\n";
            break;
        case RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY:
            std::cout << "UUID good for local only\n";
            break;
        case RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS:
            std::cout << "No hardware address for the UUID generation\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown UUID error\n";
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ASCII version of the UUID String.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    std::wcout << "Ascii Version\n";
    RPC_CSTR uuidAsciiString;
    RPC_STATUS resultTypeA = UuidToStringA(&newUUID, &uuidAsciiString);

    switch (resultTypeA)
    {
    case RPC_S_OK:
        std::cout << "UUID string generated properly\n";
        break;
    case RPC_S_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
        std::cout << "Out of memory\n";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown UUID string error\n";
    }

    std::cout << uuidAsciiString;

    resultTypeA = RpcStringFreeA(&uuidAsciiString);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Wide character version of the UUID string
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::wcout << "Wide Character Version\n";
    RPC_WSTR uuidString;
    RPC_STATUS resultTypeW = UuidToStringW(&newUUID, &uuidString);

    switch (resultTypeW)
    {
    case RPC_S_OK:
        std::cout << "UUID string generated properly\n";
        break;
    case RPC_S_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
        std::cout << "Out of memory\n";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown UUID string error\n";
    }

    std::wcout << uuidString;

    resultTypeW = RpcStringFree(&uuidString);
}
```

The output:

UUID generated properly
Ascii Version
UUID string generated properly
26d205a4-d4d5-4aa4-8837-38e91c507abc

Wide Character Version
UUID string generated properly
00B35B58

Comment: `std::wcout << uuidString << std::endl;`?

Comment: Doesn't help.  If I put a breakpoint when the RPC_WSTR is loaded it shows the same as the output a short 8 character value, not the full value for the UUID, just what appears to be the first part of the UUID

Answer (score 0):

Stupid, one of my team said maybe WCOUT doesn't know how to handle a wide RPC_WSTR.  Casting it to a LPCWSTR fixed the problem.

```
'''
    std::wcout << (LPCWSTR)uuidString;
'''
```